# Как дописать цикл for?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть скрипт который отдает результат поиска

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('form#formx').on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var msg   = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'res.php',
          data: msg,
          success: function(data) {
            //в data должен быть ответ сервера в формате JSON
            var response = JSON.parse(data); //массив в котором ваши данные
            $('#results').html(response[i].{key}); // i - номер объекта, {key} - ваш ключ из массива
          },
          error:  function(xhr, str){
                alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
            }
        });
  });
</script>
```

Если задать i(номер объекта) равным 1,2,3 и т.д. то он выведет 1 результат, как в данном случае правильно прописать цикл for для вывода всех результатов поиска?

```
$('#results').html(response[i].{key}); // i - номер объекта, {key} - ваш ключ из массива
```

Comment: for (var i in response) $('#results').html(response[i].{key})

Comment: for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                $('#results').html(response[i].name);
                }
Пробовал, нифига не выдает ничего

Comment: Вы оба промахнулись, у вас в итоге будет только последний результат

Comment: @Ne0lite попробуй сначала for(var i in response)console.log(response); - что выведет? Приложи reponse целиком к вопросу.

Comment: сработала конструкция  
 `var html='';
 for(var i in response)html+=response[i].russian
 $('#results').html(html);`
теперь надо понять как их вывести красиво и списком

Comment: @Ne0lite, попробуйте для начала разобраться сами, а так мы вам тут по кускам проект можем написать

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer у меня часть проекта идет по одному и тому же алгоритму, и поняв 1 раз, я уже использую это и в других местах, за все ответы всем огромное спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var html='';
for(var i in response)html+=response[i].{key}
$('#results').html(html);
```

**UP:** красиво и списком

```
var html='<ul>';
for(var i in response)html+='<li>'+response[i].{key}+'</li>';
html+='</ul>';
$('#results').html(html);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

как ответ.

```
for (var i in response) 
  $('#results').html(response[i].{key})
```

или

```
for (var i in response) 
  $('#results').append($("<span/>").text(response[i].{key}))
```